# order by cakephp model fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Let's say I have 3 models in a CakePHP application that have the following associations:

```
Model1
===========
var $hasMany = array(
    'Model2' => array(
        'className' => 'Model2',
        'foreignKey' => 'model1_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);

Model2
===========
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Model1' => array(
        'className' => 'Model1',
        'foreignKey' => 'model1_id'
    )
);

var $hasMany = array(
    'Model3' => array(
        'className' => 'Model3',
        'foreignKey' => 'model2_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);

Model3
===========
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Model2' => array(
        'className' => 'Model2',
        'foreignKey' => 'model2_id'
    )
);
```

How can I make a `find('all')` query on `Model3` while ordering the results by the column `created` of `Model1` first, then `Model2` and finally `Model3` (exactly in that order).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use JOINs instead of the normal 'contain' or 'recursive'.

See [Joining Tables in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).